# Read from C# Stream without busy waiting

Tags: c#, stream, busy-waiting, busy-loop

I need to read content from Stream in C#. I do not know which kind of Stream it would be. Let's assume it is Network Stream and network is very slow. So I can't read all bytes immediately. I know that 4 bytes in stream is integer and this int defines content length that we need to get from stream. How to do it without busy waiting (looping)?

```cs
private (int headerValue, bool isSuccess) ReadHeader()
{
    var bytesRead = 0;
    var headerBuffer = new byte[BufferHeaderLength];
    var headerIsReady = false;

    while (!headerIsReady)
    {
        try
        {
            var availableBytesToRead = Math.Min(BufferHeaderLength - bytesRead, underlyingStream.Length); // should be a number from 0 to 4

            bytesRead += underlyingStream.Read(headerBuffer, bytesRead, (int)availableBytesToRead);

            if (bytesRead == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            break;
        }

        headerIsReady = bytesRead == BufferHeaderLength;
    }

    var headerValue = headerIsReady ? BitConverter.ToInt32(headerBuffer, 0) : 0;

    return (headerValue, headerIsReady);
}
```

Comment: If you know it will be a network stream or similar, then it has facilities for this. If you dont know what type of stream it is, you will have to poll it for data.

Comment: [ReadAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.readasync?view=netframework-4.8) could be something to look into... but it will not remove need for looping (which not necessary the same as "busy-waiting")